# C# ObjectResult for Status 500

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc

In my `AspNetCore.Mvc` App I want to create a new `Status 500 Request Object Result`.

For `Status Code 400` I can use the following line

```
new BadRequestObjectResult("Bad Request!");
```

For `Status Code 500` I can achieve it using a `JsonResult`:

```
 new JsonResult(new {Message = "Internal Error"}) {StatusCode = 500};
```

Is there a better way to acheive this similar to a `BadRequestObjectResult`?

Comment: there's `InternalServerErrorResult`

Comment: build a class as `BadRequestObjectResult` and use that. name it maybe `InternalServerErrorObjectResult`

Answer (score 2):

try

```
return StatusCode(500, new { Message = "Internal Error." });
```

to create your own status code.

[Link to HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Answer (score 2):

Since net core 3.0 and later you can use the [Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.problem?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ObjectResult.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] string value)
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem(
            //all parameters are optional:
            //detail: "Error while processing posted data."; //an explanation, ex.Stacktrace, ...
            //instance: "/city/London"  //A reference that identifies the specific occurrence of the problem
            //title: "An error occured." //a short title, maybe ex.Message
            //statusCode: StatusCodes.Status504GatewayTimeout, //will always return code 500 if not explicitly set
            //type: "http://example.com/errors/error-123-details"  //a reference to more information
            );
    }           
}
```

It will return status-code **500** as long as no other status is explicitly set.

Answer (score 1):

The 500/Internal Server Error equivalent to `BadRequestObjectResult` is [ExceptionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.exceptionresult?view=aspnetcore-2.2&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-7.0)

> An action result that returns a Status500InternalServerError response
> and performs content negotiation on an HttpError based on an
> Exception.

Comment: @BVernon please read the answer again and look at the API spec for ExceptionResult.

Comment: Oops, my apologies!!! I definitely misread your statement. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return new StatusCodeResult((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```

Note the above does not return an object. If you want to return an object and a code you could create a class like this...

```
public class StatusCodeObjectResult : ObjectResult
{
    public StatusCodeObjectResult(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode, object value = null) 
        : base(value)
    {
        base.StatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode;
    }
}
```

And use it like this.....

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return new StatusCodeObjectResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex);
}
```

This is exactly like BadRequestObjectResult but you can now add any status code you like by using the HttpStatusCode enum. Aslo you can pass any object not only Exceptions or don't pass any object, like below.

```
return new StatusCodeObjectResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```